# DLL ativa Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

Tenho uma DLL e a mesma é ativada assim:

```
Rundll32 MinhaDll.dll
```

Inicia após o comando, faz o processo e é encerrada.

Eu preciso que ela continue na memória fazendo o monitoramento de determinados processos.

A unica forma de manter ela ativa que encontrei foi fazendo:

```
repeat application.processmessage until false;
```

Porém o processamento fica sempre em 100%.

Existe outra forma de manter ela ativa fazendo um monitoramento a cada 1 segundo?

Em um resumo, eu preciso carregar uma DLL ao iniciar o Windows e descarregar quando ele for desligado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! A comunidade fechou a pergunta porque não era possível entender claramente o problema. Editei sua pergunta, ajustando um pouco a formatação e o texto e também acrescentando seu comentário. Ela deve entrar novamente para a fila de análise. Lembre-se de que você pode editá-la a qualquer momento, caso ela não esteja de acordo com o que você queria ou para complementar com mais informações. A pergunta é sua, embora haja em certo sentido um processo colaborativo aqui no [pt.so]. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma forma de solucionar esse problema é criar um aplicação e carregar a dll nessa aplicação. Enquanto a aplicação estiver ativa a dll também estará.

Answer (score 2):

DLLs são bibliotecas de link dinâmico, isto é, elas são carregadas no momento em que um programa ou outra DLL faz referência a ela durante a execução.

Pelo que entendi do problema acima, você precisa de um programa que executa um procedimento a cada 1 segundo. A melhor forma que conheço de fazer isso no Windows é criando um serviço e registrá-lo no Service Control Manager.

Existe este tutorial http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-windows-service/7867

Serviços são programas sem interface gráfica (pois rodam em background) e são gerenciados pelo Windows.

Acredito que você esteja usando o Delphi, neste caso é muito simples criar serviços com o Delphi. Vá até o menu de assistente de um novo projeto e indique que você quer criar um projeto service do Windows.

Pela natureza de um serviço do Windows, você vai precisar implementar 3 métodos na sua classe de inicialização - Start e Stop - Eles serão chamados pelo Windows para, respectivamente, iniciar e parar o serviço. Cabe a você implementar o que o seu serviço irá fazer ao iniciar.

Como ele requer um monitoramento a cada 1 segundo, eu faria algo assim:

```
procedure TsrvPrincipal.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not self.Terminated do begin
    Sleep(1000); // Aguarda 1 segundo
    executeMonitoring();  // Realiza o monitoramento
  end;
end;
```

Ao compilar o seu serviço, o Delphi criará um arquivo executável. Para executar o serviço é necessário que você antes registre ele no Service Control Manager. Para tal, chame o seu programa com o parâmetro /INSTALL.

A partir daí, ele ficará disponível no Service Control Manager, e você poderá iniciar ou interromper ele através do Painel de Controle -> Serviços.

Espero ter ajudado.